# iOS Programatic Constraints: 'View not found in container hierarchy'

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, constraints

My iOS custom UITableViewCell requires the following layout:

| View with basic info | Long list of rectangular views |

So, the structure is as follows. I have a scroll view that will scroll horizontally, I have the "Info Container View" to the left and the list of rectangular views should appear to the right of the info container. The custom UITableViewCell is o

[image]

I was trying to add the following constraint:

```
[self.scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
                                             constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"H:[info]-space-[%@]", key]
                                             options:0 metrics:metrics
                                             views:viewsDictionary]];
```

Where info is the "Info Container" and "key" refers to the view that is being dynamically added. This results in the following error:

```
2015-01-21 16:37:44.603 AirCourts[3264:1553444] The view hierarchy is not prepared for the constraint: <NSLayoutConstraint:0x174a83840 H:[UIView:0x17018f970]-(20)-[FieldSlotView:0x1701bebc0]>
Constraint: <NSLayoutConstraint:0x174a83840 H:[UIView:0x17018f970]-(20)-[FieldSlotView:0x1701bebc0]>
(...)
View not found in container hierarchy: <UIView: 0x17018f970; frame = (0 0; 320 568); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x170e37c20>>
That view's superview: NO SUPERVIEW
```

So, it seems to be that it is referring to the fact that "Info Container" does not have a superview. Hence, I decided to test it:

[image: Error]

As you can see, it is not assumed as a descendant of the scrollview. Given that the IB hierarchy seems correct, why is this happening? Do I need to refresh the layout prior to adding constraints for some reason or is it losing hierarchy information?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you checking  descendent controller in viewDidLoad ? 
you should call this in ViewDidLayoutSubviews Or after it, Not before this one.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you get that error because of the fact that 'dynamically loaded view' is not a direct child of `scrollView` but a direct child of `infoView`.

So, in order to have AutoLayout working here, you'd rather attach that constraint to the parent view of it, which should be `infoView`, not `scrollView`.

As you can see from your logs, your infoView is `[UIView:0x17018f970]` and AutoLayout tries to find yours `[FieldSlotView:0x1701bebc0]` under its hierarchy. That's why you get following error `View not found in container hierarchy: <UIView: 0x17018f970>`

**Small tip**

When attaching constraints to a view, you can access it as `|` inside your constraint string. So, if you will replace your code to

```
[self.infoView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
                                             constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"H:|-space-[%@]", key]
                                             options:0 metrics:metrics
                                             views:viewsDictionary]];
```

you can replace `[info]` with `|` ;)

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for your reply! My idea is that the dynamic views (lets call them "fields") are siblings of the infoView. Actually, I used infoView to be able to say that the "fields" will be to the right side of the infoView in terms of layout (Hence that constraint).

Answer (score 0):

For **iOS 8.0+**, apple suggests it's safer to simply activate/deactivate your constraints. They will handle which views are affected.

Say for example you have declared

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *constraintProperty;
```

Then somewhere in your code:

```
[_constraintProperty setActive:NO];

// create constraint here

[NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[_constraintProperty]];
```

See discussion from documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622513-addconstraints
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622659-removeconstraint